# How to update document in mongodb with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am trying to update some data in the mangodb database using node js but the document won't update. I get this log message `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`
Here is my code:

I connect successfully to the data

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cinemas')
        .then(()=> console.log('connected to mongoDB....'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Could not connect to mongoDB because',err));
```

Here is the schema

```
const moviesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  acotrs:[String],
  genre: [String],
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  onCinema :Boolean
});
```

Model connection

```
const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie',movieSchema);
```

I can search the database with no issues, the only issue is the update function which does not update the database. Here is the function:

```
async function updateMovie(id){
  const result = await Movie.update({_id: id},{
    $set:{
      title: 'New Movie',
      onCinema: false
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
}
updateMovie('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd');
```

I get this log on the console `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` which tells me nothing was updated. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `{ n: 0 }` Means that the database didn't find any matches for your query, Are you sure there is a document with `5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd` as id ?

Comment: @AsafAviv yes there a document with that id

Comment: try running `const result = await Movie.findById('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd'); console.log(result);` does it find the document ?

Comment: @AsafAviv i get no log from the console, just the connected  to database message

Comment: Does that document exist in the `movies` collection?

Comment: yeap `_id:"5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd" String
tag:Array                      Array

date:2018-01-24T21:43:21.589Z  String

title:Mr Bean                  String

onCinema:false                  Boolean

__v:0                           Int32`

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await Movie.update({_id: id},{
    $set:{
      title: 'New Movie',
      onCinema: false
    }
  });
```

The update function gives  output like this.

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

try with the *findByIdAndUpdate*

```
const result = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{
    $set:{
      title: 'New Movie',
      onCinema: false
    }
  });
```

it will give the exact results in json format.

Answer (score -1):

The id you have given is in string type and _id is an ObjectId  so adding mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) should solve the issue.

```
    async function updateMovie(id){
  const result = await Movie.update({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)},{
    $set:{
      "title": 'New Movie',
      "onCinema": false
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
}
updateMovie('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd');
```

Comment: i did but still, have the same output  `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

Comment: I just edited answer have you tried like this ?  $set:{
      "title": 'New Movie',
      "onCinema": false
    }

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
`MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => { 
     let queryId = { _id: this.id }; //Get the ID of the object
     let myObj = { 
         $set: { 
           name: 'Somename' //Whatever you want to change for that ID
         }
     var db = client.db("database_name");
     db.collection("collection_name").updateOne(queryId, myObj, (err, res) => {
         if (err) {
             console.log("not Updated");
         }
         else{
            console.log("Updated");
         }
     });
}`
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.